# Difficulty with Angular controller usage from old tutorial

Tags: angularjs, ng-controller

I'm going through a basic book for Angular, and it uses a controller to set up a field. However, I don't get the expected output. Searching here and elsewhere, it looks like I'm invoking it correctly, but something's not working. Anything obviously wrong? Anything else to try? Details below. Thanks.

Document html:

```
<html lang="en" ng-app ng-controller="AppCtrl">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title></title>
  <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controller.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Hello, {{name || 'World'}}</h1>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
</body>
```

controller.js:

```
function AppCtrl($scope) {
 $scope.name = "World";
```

(function closing brace lost by code formatting)

Expected output is "Hello, World", but I get "Hello, {{name || 'World'}}"

Comment: What's the error in the console? Guessing it's because you're missing the app name in ng-app and then also ng-controller...

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.3](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the ng-app and the module in controller.

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
 $scope.name = "World";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head> 
</head>

<body>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <h1>Hello, {{name || 'World'}}</h1>
  <input type="text" ng-model="name">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hmmmm. I'm using a 2015 Pack book called "Learning Web Development with Bootstrap and AngularJS". I see from other searching that most examples look like yours, but I think I'm typing in the book example verbatim. Is the book too old? Did I pull in a newer Angular version when I recently downloaded it? Thanks.

Comment: this is the way it should be in general.

Comment: OK. Looks like I need to go through a basic Angular tutorial . . . . . Would my code ever have worked in an older version? How could it have worked for the book author? Thanks.

Comment: mark as answer if it helped. it must be using the earier version of angualr with global controller.

Comment: Marked as answer. The first few examples in the W3Schools tutorial look like your lines, so I guess I'm on my way to learn standard/current Angular. Thanks again.

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Migrating to V1.3](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration#migrating-from-1-2-to-1-3)